Kotlin genetic algorithm outputs same value twice
I have a problem with this genetic algorithm where it outputs two of the same values (locations) in finalGen.chromosome.
Chromosome.kt
package com.example.gotravel01
class Chromosome(private val nodesList: MutableList<LocationGA>, private val dist_matrix: Array<DoubleArray>) {
    val chrMethods = ChromosomeMethods()
    var chromosome: MutableList<LocationGA> = nodesList
    var cost: Double = calculate_distance()
    var fitness_value: Double = if (cost != 0.0) 1 / cost else Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY

    fun calculate_distance(): Double {
        var total_distance = 0.0
        for (i in 0 until chromosome.size - 1) {
            total_distance += dist_matrix[chromosome[i].id - 1][chromosome[i + 1].id - 1]
        }
        return total_distance
    }
}

ChromosomeMethods.kt (
package com.example.gotravel01

class ChromosomeMethods {
    val dataset = mutableListOf<LocationGA>()
    fun generateLocationDataset(dataArray: Array<Array<String>>): MutableList<LocationGA> {
        for ((index, element) in dataArray.withIndex()) {
            val id = index + 1
            val name = element[1]
            val x = element[5].toDouble()
            val y = element[6].toDouble()
            dataset.add(LocationGA(id, name, x, y))
        }
        return dataset
    }

    fun generate_dist_matrix(nodes_list: List<LocationGA>): Array<DoubleArray> {
        val node_number = nodes_list.size
        var matrix = Array(node_number){ DoubleArray(node_number) {0.0} }

        for(i in 0..(node_number)-1) {
            for (j in 0..(node_number)-1) {
                if(i != j){
                    var x1 = nodes_list[i].xCoord
                    var y1 = nodes_list[i].yCoord
                    var x2 = nodes_list[j].xCoord
                    var y2 = nodes_list[j].yCoord

                    matrix[i][j] = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x1-x2, 2.0) + Math.pow(y1-y2, 2.0) );
                }
            }
        }
        return matrix
    }
    val dist_matrix = generate_dist_matrix(dataset)

}

GeneticAlgorithm.kt
package com.example.gotravel01

import kotlin.random.Random

class GeneticAlgorithm {
    fun create_random_list(node_list: MutableList<LocationGA>): MutableList<LocationGA> {
        var start = node_list[0]
        val temp = node_list.subList(1, node_list.size).shuffled().toMutableList()
        temp.add(0, start)
        temp.add(start)
        return temp
    }

    fun initialize(dataset: MutableList<LocationGA>, pop_size: Int, dist_matrix: Array<DoubleArray>): MutableList<Chromosome> {
        val chr = ChromosomeMethods()
        var initial_pop: MutableList<Chromosome> = ArrayList()
        for(i in 0 until pop_size){
            var temp = create_random_list(dataset)
            initial_pop.add(Chromosome(temp, dist_matrix))
        }
        return initial_pop
    }
    fun selection(population: List<Chromosome>): Chromosome {
        val ch1 = population[Random.nextInt(population.size)]
        val ch2 = population[Random.nextInt(population.size)]
        return if (ch1.fitness_value > ch2.fitness_value) ch1 else ch2
    }

    fun crossover(chr1: Chromosome, chr2: Chromosome): Pair<MutableList<LocationGA>, MutableList<LocationGA>> {
        val crossPoint = Random.nextInt(1, 4)
        val crossedChr1 = chr1.chromosome.toMutableList()
        val crossedChr2 = chr2.chromosome.toMutableList()
        for (i in 0 until crossPoint) {
            val temp = crossedChr1[i]
            crossedChr1[i] = crossedChr2[i]
            crossedChr2[i] = temp
        }
        return Pair(crossedChr1, crossedChr2)
    }

    /*fun mutation(chromosome: MutableList<LocationGA>): MutableList<LocationGA> {
        val swapIndex1 = Random.nextInt(1, chromosome.size - 1)
        val swapIndex2 = Random.nextInt(1, chromosome.size - 1)
        chromosome[swapIndex1] = chromosome[swapIndex2].also {chromosome[swapIndex2] = chromosome[swapIndex1]}
        return chromosome
    }*/

    fun mutation(chromosome: MutableList<LocationGA>): MutableList<LocationGA> {
        val mutatedChromosome = chromosome.toMutableList() // Copy the chromosome
        val swapIndex1 = Random.nextInt(1, mutatedChromosome.size - 1)
        val swapIndex2 = Random.nextInt(1, mutatedChromosome.size - 1)
        mutatedChromosome[swapIndex1] = mutatedChromosome[swapIndex2].also { mutatedChromosome[swapIndex2] = mutatedChromosome[swapIndex1] }
        return mutatedChromosome
    }


    fun findBest(generation: List<Chromosome>): Chromosome {
        return generation.minByOrNull { it.cost }!!
    }

    fun newGeneration(previousGen: List<Chromosome>, mutationRate: Double, dist_matrix: Array<DoubleArray>): List<Chromosome> {
        val chr = ChromosomeMethods()
        val newGeneration = mutableListOf<Chromosome>()
        newGeneration.add(findBest(previousGen))
        repeat(previousGen.size / 2) {
            val parent1 = selection(previousGen)
            val parent2 = selection(previousGen)
            val (child1, child2) = crossover(parent1, parent2)
            if (Random.nextDouble() < mutationRate) {
                mutation(child2)
            }
            newGeneration.add(Chromosome(child1, dist_matrix))
            newGeneration.add(Chromosome(child2, dist_matrix))
        }
        return newGeneration
    }
}

Main.kt
package com.example.gotravel01

class Main {
    val chr = ChromosomeMethods()

    fun execute_GA(dataArray: Array<Array<String>>): Chromosome {
        val chr = ChromosomeMethods()
        val GA = GeneticAlgorithm()
        val dataset = chr.generateLocationDataset(dataArray)
        val distMatrix = chr.generate_dist_matrix(dataset)
        val generations = 100
        val popSize = 10
        val mutationRate = 0.1

        var generatedPop = GA.initialize(dataset, popSize, distMatrix)

        repeat(generations) { i ->
            val newGen = GA.newGeneration(generatedPop, mutationRate, distMatrix)
            val bestCost = GA.findBest(newGen).cost
            if (bestCost == 0.0) {
                return@repeat
            }
            println("Generation ${i + 1}: Best Cost = $bestCost")
            generatedPop = newGen.toMutableList()
        }

        val finalGen = GA.findBest(generatedPop)
        return finalGen
    }
}

I'm not sure what's wrong. I changed the mutation value, which helped give a different chromosome, but the problem persists. Any help please?
Thank you.

I've looked at it further, it seems changing the number of generations and mutation value helps. However, the results change every time.
